# How to mark up/edit short versions of pep band songs?

Tags: notation, sheet-music

### *Question*

My band recently printed a brand new pep band flip book and we are required to make edits to the songs so that they are shorter.  Since the books are nice and new I am curious as to if their is a better way to delete and skip measures than simply crossing them off and/or drawing arrows.  Currently, allot of people use a combination of brackets, numbers, arrows, and crossing things off.  I would just use the Coda symbol, but that is technically improper.  Perhaps I should just go with "to measure X"?

### **Example**

- Song 1.long/original is 20 measures long.
- Song 1.A is from measures 1 to 8.
- Song 1.B is from measures 11 to 15 and skip to measures 19 to 20.
- Song 1.C is from measures 5 to 12 and skip to measures 19 to 20.

Comment: How is the coda technically improper? Are crossing out and arrows, or “go to” more proper?

Comment: Good point, except the coda already has a musical definition and I was wondering if their was a method that was common/formal and well defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standardized system for this. Anything that works for you — "to X", or even a coda symbol — is fine.

Allowing the book will be used only by you, just make sure your markings are easy to follow at a glance. To add a possibility to the ones you mentioned, you could color-code (e.g., highlight or under-/over-line) the played parts.

If the book is something that others will also use, then you'll want non-permanent markings. So, light pencil. Consider covering the unplayed parts with post-it notes rather than Xs.

For the best of all worlds, make your own copies. Either just make copies to mark up however you like, or cover the skipped measures with blank paper and then copy. In the latter case, you'll wind up with a "clean" version for yourself, and an unmarked original if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a "standard" notation for a skipped section of music you can use the Latin term: *vide*.  Use "**vi-**" to mark the start, and "**-de**" to mark the end, with dashes spanning the section to be cut (i.e. **vi- - -de**).  But whether the performers will recognise this notation is perhaps unlikely; and you should have a footnote.

From the Dolmetsch Music Dictionary, [Vi - Vl](https://www.dolmetsch.com/defsv1.htm):

> #### vide
>
> *vide* is used as a mark in the score to show where a cut is to be made - the cut begins where *Vi*, sometimes followed by a long hyp[h]en (-), is marked and ends at the point where *de* is marked, so the performer skips, without a break, from the begin[n]ing to the end of the cut and continues on from there

From Elaine Gould's *Behind Bars – The Definitive Guide to Music Notation*, p. 496:

> #### Optional cuts
>
> Encountered usually in stage works, the relevant passage is marked at the top of the system with the divided word **vi-** **-de** (Latin, ’look!’) and an explanatory footnote:
>
> [image: excerpt of score showing "vide" notation, with "vi-" above a coda symbol marking the start of the optional cut, and "-de" above a rehearsal mark at the end of the cut, a footnote below the score explains the notation explicitly]
>
> This is sometimes accompanied by a coda sign at the beginning or at both ends of the cut (the second coda sign is optional; as in a coda, this sign indicates a point from which to skip ahead).

---

For your particular example though, it seems like you are trying to deal with *several* different versions of the same piece, all represented on the same sheet of music.  You'll probably want to use rehearsal marks.  These are just large boxed measure numbers (as in the image above) or letters placed at the top of the score.  Explain the different versions as you have; e.g. Song 1.B: mm. 11–15, 19–20.  But be careful with the numbers because mm. 11-15 is a range that includes measure 15, but will stop at the [16] mark.

If you really want to have *all* the different versions encoded on the same sheet music this is inevitably going to be somewhat messy (especially given that they overlap).